# Circuit Diagrams and Mesh Analysis LaTeX

Tags: circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib, circuits

So I am trying to create a very simple circuit this here is my code:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american, scale = 1.5][americanvoltages]
  \draw (0,0)
  to[V=$V_{in}$] (0,2) % The voltage source
  to[R, v^<=$R_1$] (2,2) % The resistor
  to[C, v^<=$C_1$] (2,1) % Capacitor One
  to[C, v^<=$C_2$] (2,0) %Capacitor Two
  to[L, v^<=$L_1$] (0,0); %Inductor One

\draw[thin, <-, >=triangle 45] (1.25,0.5) arc (-60:170:0.5);

\end{circuitikz}
```

All that I would like to do is be able to write i_1 inside the drawn thin circle to denote current flowing throughout circuit.

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the `\draw` line to

```
\draw[thin, <-, >=triangle 45] (1,1)node{$i_1$}  ++(-60:0.5) arc (-60:170:0.5);
```

is perhaps what you're after.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document} 
\begin{circuitikz}[american, scale = 1.5][americanvoltages]
  \draw (0,0)
  to[V=$V_{in}$] (0,2) % The voltage source
  to[R, v^<=$R_1$] (2,2) % The resistor
  to[C, v^<=$C_1$] (2,1) % Capacitor One
  to[C, v^<=$C_2$] (2,0) %Capacitor Two
  to[L, v^<=$L_1$] (0,0); %Inductor One

\draw[thin, <-, >=triangle 45] (1,1)node{$i_1$}  ++(-60:0.5) arc (-60:170:0.5);

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Both great answers and really quick too!! Thanks a lot you are both Lifesavers :D –

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a `path picture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american, scale = 1.5][americanvoltages]
  \draw (0,0)
  to[V=$V_{in}$] (0,2) % The voltage source
  to[R, v^<=$R_1$] (2,2) % The resistor
  to[C, v^<=$C_1$] (2,1) % Capacitor One
  to[C, v^<=$C_2$] (2,0) %Capacitor Two
  to[L, v^<=$L_1$] (0,0); %Inductor One

\draw[thin, <-, >=triangle 45,path picture={
            \node[anchor=center]  at (path picture bounding box.center) {$i_1$};
            }] (1.25,0.5) arc (-60:170:0.5);

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Note that I have also used `\usetikzlibrary{bending}` so that the arrow head bends neatly.

[image]

Comment: Both great answers and really quick too!!

Thanks a lot you are both Lifesavers :D

Comment: @ANT1: You are welcome. Now that you have more than 15 rep points, you can upvote both answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try simple bending arrow.

```
    \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{bending}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american, scale = 1.5][american voltages]
    \draw (0,0)
      to[V=$V_{in}$] (0,2) % The voltage source
      to[R, v^<=$R_1$] (2,2) % The resistor
      to[C, v^<=$C_1$] (2,1) % Capacitor One
      to[C, v^<=$C_2$] (2,0) %Capacitor Two
      to[L, v^<=$L_1$] (0,0); %Inductor One

      \draw[-stealth]  (0.5,1.5) to [bend left=90] node[left,node font=\tiny]{$i_1$} (0.5,0.5);     
      \end{circuitikz}

     \end{document}
```

[image: Arrows with little bending]
You get arrows with little bending.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this way:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american, scale = 1.5][american voltages]
\draw (0,0)
  to[V=$V_{in}$] (0,2) % The voltage source
  to[R, v^<=$R_1$] (2,2) % The resistor
  to[C, v^<=$C_1$] (2,1) % Capacitor One
  to[C, v^<=$C_2$] (2,0) %Capacitor Two
  to[L, v^<=$L_1$] (0,0); %Inductor One

\draw [magenta,latex-] (1.0,0.5) node[above,color=magenta]{$i_a$} arc (-90:165:5mm); 

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]